# How to add new column family to an existing HBase table?

Tags: hbase, column-family, nosql

I created a table by

```
create 'tablename', 'columnfamily1'
```

Now is it possible to add another column family 'columnfamily2'? What is the method?

Comment: Take a look of this: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#addColumn%28byte[],%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor%29

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It seems

```
alter 'tablename', 'columnfamily2'
```

does the trick. 
One may, disable 'tablename' first. However, it works fine even if enabled.

```
hbase(main):015:0> alter 'tablename', {NAME=> 'columnfamily2'}
Updating all regions with the new schema...
0/1 regions updated.
1/1 regions updated.
Done.
```

Comment: Disabling & Enabling the table is required if "base.online.schema.update.enable" not set to "true"

Answer (score 9):

```
alter 'tablename', NAME => 'newcolumnfamily', VERSIONS => 50
```

you can specify various properties of the new column family separated by a comma (,)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider some GUI solutions than you can easily do it with [HAdmin](https://hadmin.io/?utm_source=so&utm_campaign=addCf). Simply press the "+" button in the "Alter table" page and add your new column family with all settings you need.
[image]